# Winbugs_ multiple definition of node sigma

Tags: winbugs

I  tried to run a model in winbugs, but I got an output that says " multiple definitions of node sigma"  and I don't know ho to fix it. Would someone able to help me?

This is the code:

```
model{
    for(i in 1:10){
    for (t in 1:2){
    #  y[i,t] =collision at intersection i in year t
    # mi[i,t] and ma [i,t] = major and minor traffic volume at intersection i at   year t
    #likehood
    y[i,t] ~ dpois(theta[i,t]) 
    # link function (for collision rate)
    theta[i,t] <- lambda[i,t]  * rate[i,t]
    rate [i,t] <- (mi[i,t] + ma[i,t]) /1000
    log(lambda[i,t]) <- beta0 + beta1*log(mi[i,t]) + beta2*log(ma[i,t]) + c[i]
    c[i] ~ dnorm (0.0, tau)
}
    # prior distribution
    beta0 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
    beta1 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
    beta2 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
    tau ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
    sigma <- 1/ sqrt(tau)
}
}

#data
y[ ,1]  y[ ,2]  mi[ ,1] ma[ ,1] mi[ ,2] ma[ ,2] 
5   3   550 660 561 680 
2   1   600 720 612 742 
3   5   580 696 591.6   717 
4   7   620 744 632.4   766 
5   6   700 840 714 865 
4   3   710 852 724.2   878 
5   3   680 816 693.6   840 
8   4   800 960 816 989 
7   5   750 900 765 927 
10  8   810 972 826.2   1001    
END
```

Comment: the data:y[ ,1] y[ ,2] mi[ ,1] ma[ ,1] mi[ ,2] ma[ ,2] 
5 3 550 660 561 680 
2 1 600 720 612 742 
3 5 580 696 591.6 717 
4 7 620 744 632.4 766 
5 6 700 840 714 865 
4 3 710 852 724.2 878 
5 3 680 816 693.6 840 
8 4 800 960 816 989 
7 5 750 900 765 927 
10 8 810 972 826.2 1001 
END

Answer (score 0):

The end brace for the for(i in 1:10) loop is in the wrong place - it is currently at the end of the model, so beta0, beta1, beta2, tau and sigma are being defined 10 times.  Instead you want:

```
model{
    for(i in 1:10){
        for (t in 1:2){
            #  y[i,t] =collision at intersection i in year t
            # mi[i,t] and ma [i,t] = major and minor traffic volume at intersection i at   year t
            #likehood
            y[i,t] ~ dpois(theta[i,t]) 
            # link function (for collision rate)
            theta[i,t] <- lambda[i,t]  * rate[i,t]
            rate [i,t] <- (mi[i,t] + ma[i,t]) /1000
            log(lambda[i,t]) <- beta0 + beta1*log(mi[i,t]) + beta2*log(ma[i,t]) + c[i]
            c[i] ~ dnorm (0.0, tau)
        }
    }

    # prior distribution
    beta0 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
    beta1 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
    beta2 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
    tau ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
    sigma <- 1/ sqrt(tau)
}
```

Using more strict/consistent indentation in your model code helps to make errors like this more obvious to spot.

-- EDIT --

There is also a problem with the following line:

```
c[i] ~ dnorm (0.0, tau)
```

c[i] is defined within the (t in 1:2) loop, so each c[i] is defined twice. Either you want to define c[i] outside the t loop, or index c by i AND t.  I'm guessing it's the former so that c[i] is a random effect of intersection, but it may also make sense to have this at observation level (so that it is an over-dispersed Poisson model), or one of each. A random effect of intersection would look like:

```
model{
    for(i in 1:10){
        for (t in 1:2){
            #  y[i,t] =collision at intersection i in year t
            # mi[i,t] and ma [i,t] = major and minor traffic volume at intersection i at   year t
            #likehood
            y[i,t] ~ dpois(theta[i,t]) 
            # link function (for collision rate)
            theta[i,t] <- lambda[i,t]  * rate[i,t]
            rate [i,t] <- (mi[i,t] + ma[i,t]) /1000
            log(lambda[i,t]) <- beta0 + beta1*log(mi[i,t]) + beta2*log(ma[i,t]) + c[i]
        }
        c[i] ~ dnorm (0.0, tau)
    }

    # prior distribution
    beta0 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
    beta1 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
    beta2 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0E-6)
    tau ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
    sigma <- 1/ sqrt(tau)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matt for helping me out. I will pay more attention on the indentantion and braces.

Comment: I tried to run the code, but now I got "multiple definition of node c[1]" . Would you be able to help me out again? Thank you.